# Python logging debug level wont go away

Tags: python, logging, scripting

I'm trying to disable DEBUG logging in Python 2.6.6 that appears to be triggered when running certain commands... and I've tried what appears to be every solution out there and I still keep getting the unwanted output.

I even included:

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Same results...

When I run the same command (test.cmd) via the cmd prompt, I get the expected output. When I run the same command via a python Script, using this code:

```
p = Popen([test, "report"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read()
print output
```

I get the following (and it keeps going):

```
07/06/18 08:13:16 DEBUG : Enter:  HTTPSender::invoke
Enter:  HTTPSender::invoke
07/06/18 08:13:16 DEBUG : XML sent:
XML sent:
07/06/18 08:13:16 DEBUG : ---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
07/06/18 08:13:16 DEBUG : POST /awstestservice/soap HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "awstestReport"
Content-Length: 327
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not convinced that these DEBUG lines come from python. What do you pass as `test` in your Popen instantiation?

Comment: it calls the 'report' function from test.cmd... and if i run it via the cmd prompt, i don't get all that DEBUG info above... and if I turn on DEBUG on test.cmd (there's a setting), it gives me a different DEBUG than above leading me to believe it has to come from Python

Comment: And what exactly is test.cmd? Also, did you explicitly configure logging anywhere in your code?

Comment: It calls other java files to connect to an API to retrieve information; no I started adding logging to the top of the code during trial/error to see if I can disable, latest one I used was logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL) which resulted in same behavior, but OOB I haven't configured logging at all

Comment: But then it can't come from Python logging. If you don't configure handlers and formatters, then logging does nothing visible, even if Popen would internally create a logger and log to it, which it does not do, to my knowledge. Also, you seem to be capturing the unwanted lines when reading from stdout, so it's not coming from your interpreter but from the process it spawned. maybe _maybe_ MAYBE it has sth. to do with the fact that you redirect stderr into stdout in your Popen, but I have no way to tell from what you shared here

Comment: That's good information, I will look into that further...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the following workaround:

```
#Verify the report was created
output = p.stdout.read()
status = output.rfind('Report created')

#Update Report Status
if (status!=-1):
 print ("Report Created")
else:
print ("Error")
```

Not  sure if that would help anyone but it resolved the issue with me...